# Python: Writing values in pandas from one frame to another doesn´t work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have one dataframe where i have several rows belonging to the same group. I now want to add one line per group to a new dataframe with the median value of each column of the old. Therefore i coded the following: I go to every row in the DF and lookup if the group name was already processed. If not i want to write the median into the new DF 
`

```
for i in df2.index:
    prot=str(df2.loc[i, 'Proteins'])


    if prot in c:
        pass

    else:

        c.append(prot)
        temp=df2[df2['Proteins'].apply(lambda x: x == prot)]
        df3.loc[i, 'Gene Names']=temp.loc[i, 'Gene Names']
        df3.loc[i, 'Proteins']=temp.loc[i, 'Proteins']
        df3.loc[i, 'Median 0']=temp['H/L 0'].median()
        df3.loc[i, 'Median 1']=temp['H/L 1'].median()
        df3.loc[i, 'Median 2']=temp['H/L 2'].median()
        df3.loc[i, 'Median 3']=temp['H/L 3'].median()
        df3.loc[i, 'Median 4']=temp['H/L 4'].median()
        df3.loc[i, 'Median 5']=temp['H/L 5'].median()
        df3.loc[i, 'Median 6']=temp['H/L 6'].median()
        df3.loc[i, 'Median 7']=temp['H/L 7'].median()
        df3.loc[i, 'Median 8']=temp['H/L 8'].median()
        df3.loc[i, 'Median 9']=temp['H/L 9'].median() `
```

Data frame looks like this:

```
    A  B  C  D
    XX 2  2  2
    Y  4  4  4
    YX 2  2  2
    XX 2  3  2
```

Now it should collapse into the new data frame:

```
    A  B  C  D
    XX 2 2.5 2
    Y  4  4  4
    YX 2  2  2
```

But if i do this: it raises my an error:

```
KeyError: 'the label [2311] is not in the [index]'
```

I thought i create the index by assigning it with `df3.loc[i, 'column']=XXX`

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you try to achieve `groupby`?

```
df.groupby('A').median()
```

```
     B    C    D
A                
XX  2.0  2.5  2.0
Y   4.0  4.0  4.0
YX  2.0  2.0  2.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this also work if i have more columns with non numeric values? Sometimes I have the problem that .median() does not work if i don´t specify the column and there are non numeric columns.

Comment: Yes It will ignore the non numeric values. You should specify a column to group the data.